# Az copy from production to development storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Command:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/image /Dest:http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/rawimage /SourceKey:<account-key> /DestType:blob
```

Error message:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect. Specify exactly one of the following parameters for the account to which the destination is to be written: "/DestKey" or "/DestSAS". Alternatively, you can include the SAS token as a query string in the destination URI.

Where can I find the development storage key (i.e the /DestKey)?

Comment: Please change your account key immediately as you accidentally shared actual account key.

Comment: @GauravMantri Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They key and account to use with the storage emulator are:

Account name: devstoreaccount1

Account key: Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==

Also, for reference, check out [Authenticating requests against the storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#authenticating-requests-against-the-storage-emulator), it talks about how to work the storage account emulator in more detail.